# Guarantee that multiple FK fields belongs to the same row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship

On a SaS project (Software as a Service), imagine this scenario:

The main table for customers, those who use the application, is **tenant** and it primary key is the column **id**.

I have 3 tables to manage data from tenants and one specific table to manage a functionality of *vacancies*:

**Period**, **Unity** and **Shift** all those with *PK id* and *FK tenant_id*.

My table **vacancy** have 3 Foreign Keys

- period_id - References to "Period" table
- unity_id - References to "Unity" table
- shift_id - References to "Shift" table

### **Now the problem:**

I need to guarantee that all these 3 FK's are reference to rows on Period, Unity and Shift tables that belong to the same Customer on the tenant table.

I was clear in my explanation?

Maybe i can create a Trigger to handle those validations. I really don't know if SGBD already have resources to do with that.

For information: I'm using SQL Server with Eloquent ORM. But, if really exists a solution for this, the best would be one that who works everywhere.

Comment: In this case have just a single foreign key to the id column of the tenant table. If the tenant table does not have a single id column, then create one.

Comment: Do you have the option of changing the table structure or must you work withinthe tables structure given here?

Comment: Extend the table `vacancy` by the `customer_id` and then change the three tables `period`, `unity` and `shirt` to have a composite PK consisting of their old ID and `customer_id` and add a FK from the three tables PK to a part of the PK of `vacancy`.

Comment: Shadow - the problem is a little bit more complex than this.

HLGEM - yes, i will need to change the table structure.

Smutje - I marked other answer as accepted cause it was more clear to understand. But you're right.

Comment: @RicardoVigattiCoelho technically, my answer was a comment and therefore not acceptable in terms of Stackoverflow, so never mind! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Ensure that your `tenant_id` is defined as `NOT NULL` on the tables `Period`, `Unity` and `Shift`.

2) Create the following unique keys on that tables:

- Period(tenant_id, period_id)
- Unity(tenant_id, unity_id)
- Shift(tenant_id, shift_id)

3) Define column `tenant_id` for table `vacancy` as `NOT NULL`.

4) Define the folowing FKs on table `vacancy`:

- (tenant_id, period_id) referencing Period(tenant_id, period_id)
- (tenant_id, unity_id) referencing Unity(tenant_id, unity_id)
- (tenant_id, shift_id) referencing Shift(tenant_id, shift_id)

This way you can guarantee that every linked row has the same `tenant_id`.

Comment: Awesome. I did some tests and it's exactly what i need.